# Use multiple LocalizationsDelegates in Flutter

Tags: flutter, internationalization, dart-intl

I'm facing an issue where I'm trying to use multiple `LocalizationsDelegates` in a `MaterialApp`.

I'm using the Dart `intl` tools to provide translations to my labels. When I have multiple `LocalizationsDelegates` only the one that is specified the first gets the translated values. The labels of the next delegate, get the default value provided in the `Intl.message()` function.

### Short, self contained, correct example

I've set up a minimal project as an example of this issue [on GitHub](https://github.com/dumazy/flutter_multiple_localizationsdelegates).

### Code snippets

In the `MaterialApp`, I define a bunch of `localizationsDelegates`, including two app specific ones: `DogLocalizationsDelegate` and `CatLocalizationsDelegate`.

```
MaterialApp(
  // other properties
  locale: Locale("en"),
  localizationsDelegates: [
    CatLocalizationsDelegate(),
    DogLocalizationsDelegate(),
    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
  ],
  supportedLocales: [
    const Locale('en'),
    const Locale('nl'),
  ],
);
```

The delegates have the same boilerplate code, but provide different labels.
Here's how the `DogLocalizations` and its `DogLocalizationsDelegate` look like.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'messages_all.dart';

class DogLocalizations {
  static Future<DogLocalizations> load(Locale locale) {
    final String name = locale.languageCode;
    final String localeName = Intl.canonicalizedLocale(name);
    return initializeMessages(localeName).then((_) {
      Intl.defaultLocale = localeName;
      return DogLocalizations();
    });
  }

  static DogLocalizations of(BuildContext context) {
    return Localizations.of<DogLocalizations>(context, DogLocalizations);
  }

  String get bark {
    return Intl.message(
      '<insert dog sound>',
      name: 'bark',
    );
  }
}

class DogLocalizationsDelegate extends LocalizationsDelegate<DogLocalizations> {
  const DogLocalizationsDelegate();

  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) => ['en', 'nl'].contains(locale.languageCode);

  @override
  Future<DogLocalizations> load(Locale locale) => DogLocalizations.load(locale);

  @override
  bool shouldReload(DogLocalizationsDelegate old) => false;
}
```

The `CatLocalizations` are the same, but with a `meow` String getter. Full example in the GitHub project.

### Commands used to generate translations files

I'm using multiple extraction and generation commands instead of having multiple files in one command. This is because I'm actually having this problem with a library (with its own labels) and a consumer of that library (that also has its own labels).

1. Extract labels of both cats and dogs

`flutter pub run intl_translation:extract_to_arb --output-dir=lib/cat_labels/gen lib/cat_labels/CatLabels.dart`

`flutter pub run intl_translation:extract_to_arb --output-dir=lib/dog_labels/gen lib/dog_labels/DogLabels.dart`

2. Translate the generated `intl_messages.arb` to have two language files

   - intl_en.arb
   - intl_nl.arb
     And then add the correct translated values to these files.
3. Generate the dart files from ARB

`flutter pub run intl_translation:generate_from_arb --output-dir=lib/cat_labels lib/cat_labels/CatLabels.dart lib/cat_labels/gen/intl_*.arb`

`flutter pub run intl_translation:generate_from_arb --output-dir=lib/dog_labels lib/dog_labels/DogLabels.dart lib/dog_labels/gen/intl_*.arb`

### Issue

In this demo project, having the following order of delegates:

```
// main.dart (line 20)
DogLocalizationsDelegate(),
CatLocalizationsDelegate(),
```

will give the translation for the `bark` label, but not for the `meow` label.

When **switching** it:

```
// main.dart (line 20)
CatLocalizationsDelegate(),
DogLocalizationsDelegate(),
```

will give the translation for the `meow` label, but not for the `bark` label.

### Why multiple localization delegates

In case you're wondering why: I'm using labels in a library and in the consumer apps of that library.
**Important** to know is that it's not (really) possible to specify both localization files in the same generator command because of this.

Comment: Multiple `LocalizationsDelegate`s worked for me. It's hard to say what is wrong with your code cause the sample project does not contain neither `DogLocalizationsDelegate` nor `CatLocalizationsDelegate` code.

Comment: Beautifully written question! for whomever is looking for an answer, it's not just a simple one, but also well explained and with code example - https://medium.com/dev-artel/localization-in-multi-module-project-with-intl-utils-cc82b3a41113

Answer (score 5):

From what I learned, no, you can’t use multiple localizations delegates like this. That is because intl’s `initializeMessages` can only be called once per locale.

So in your example, once your `CatLocalizationsDelegate` runs `initializeMessages`, the one for `DogLocalizationsDelegate` has no effect. That’s why you are only seeing the translation `Meow!` but not Dog’s, or whichever one gets to run it first.

For additional reading, check out https://phrase.com/blog/posts/how-to-internationalize-a-flutter-app/ and please share feedback at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41437.

Comment: Any news on this interesting topic ? I get the same issue and did not find the solution. how to internationalize package translation with arb / intl process without this feature ?

Comment: Well, if you intrested, I've made this `CustomTranslationLoader` to load and compose localization files from different basePaths: https://pastebin.com/Lq6W8SGJ

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [multiple_localizations](https://pub.dev/packages/multiple_localization) package. it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution with a dedicated flutter package available here: [multiple_localization](https://pub.dev/packages/multiple_localization)