# Use multiple localizationsDelegates with existing files generated with l10n.yaml

Tags: flutter

I have multiple localizationsDelegates:

```dart
localizationsDelegates: const [
  AppLocalizations.delegate,
  DictLibLocalizations.delegate,
],
```

Unfortunately when I switch locales I get an error:

```
The following message was thrown:
Warning: This application's locale, si, is not supported by all of its localization delegates.

• A MaterialLocalizations delegate that supports the si locale was not found.
• A CupertinoLocalizations delegate that supports the si locale was not found.

The declared supported locales for this app are: en, si, ta
```

There is a similar question here: [Use multiple LocalizationsDelegates in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57267141/use-multiple-localizationsdelegates-in-flutter). They have the same problem I do, in which initializeMessages is only called once, but the difference is whereas they are building the delegates manually, I am using delegates generated with the gen-l10n tool.

There is a package called multiple_localizations that can help with the manual delegate case, but [it doesn't support these autogenerated delegates(https://github.com/Innim/flutter_multiple_localization/issues/9).

This commit demonstrates how I've had to work around this issue for now, which only really works because one of my localization classes (`AppLocalizations`) is really small: https://github.com/banool/slsl_dictionary/commit/ddf2e43ae73c886ce960d6039e1d4c989b2986b5#diff-48cb45ff0e4d9f0fdd91b4de5babea91f2636e6cf3fa72647148bea9ce399a83.

How can I make my app work with multiple localizations?